# Pecl cant compile Imagick extention on macOS Big Sur, how fix it?

Tags: php, c, macos, imagick, pecl

I try to install imagick extention for php 8 (or ph 7.4) and pecl cant compile imagick from sources, but pecl install other extentions for php

xcode installed -- yes
php installed -- yes
imagemagick installed -- yes
pecl installed --yes

installation log

```
workhard@mbp % pecl install imagick
downloading imagick-3.4.4.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.4.4.tgz (253,434 bytes)
.....................................................done: 253,434 bytes
19 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20200930
Zend Module Api No:      20200930
Zend Extension Api No:   420200930
Please provide the prefix of ImageMagick installation [autodetect] : 
building in /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-workhard3KXfYN/imagick-3.4.4
running: /private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php/bin/php-config --with-imagick
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php/main -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/pecl/20200930
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking whether to enable the imagick extension... yes, shared
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... checking Testing /usr/local/bin/MagickWand-config... It exists
found in /usr/local/bin/MagickWand-config
checking if ImageMagick version is at least 6.2.4... found version 7.0.10 Q16 HDRI
checking for MagickWand.h or magick-wand.h header... /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.10-48/include/ImageMagick-7/MagickWand/MagickWand.h
checking PHP version is at least 5.3.2... yes. found 8.0.0
libs
-L/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.10-48/lib -lMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI -lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI


checking for MagickGetVersion... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for ld used by cc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 786432
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fno-common
checking if cc PIC flag -fno-common works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... no
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the cc linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin20.1.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no

creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: patching config.h.in
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/ksh /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-workhard3KXfYN/imagick-3.4.4/libtool --mode=compile cc -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-workhard3KXfYN/imagick-3.4.4/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-workhard3KXfYN/imagick-3.4.4/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php/main -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.10-48/include/ImageMagick-7  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.10-48/include/ImageMagick-7 -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c -o imagick_file.lo
mkdir .libs
 cc -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-workhard3KXfYN/imagick-3.4.4/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-workhard3KXfYN/imagick-3.4.4/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php/main -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.10-48/include/ImageMagick-7 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.10-48/include/ImageMagick-7 -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/imagick_file.o
In file included from /private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:22:
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:61:108: error: expected ')'
zend_bool php_imagick_file_init(struct php_imagick_file_t *file, const char *filename, size_t filename_len TSRMLS_DC);
                                                                                                           ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:61:32: note: to match this '('
zend_bool php_imagick_file_init(struct php_imagick_file_t *file, const char *filename, size_t filename_len TSRMLS_DC);
                               ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:65:54: error: expected ')'
int php_imagick_safe_mode_check(const char *filename TSRMLS_DC);
                                                     ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:65:32: note: to match this '('
int php_imagick_safe_mode_check(const char *filename TSRMLS_DC);
                               ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:68:134: error: expected ')'
php_imagick_rw_result_t php_imagick_read_file(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC);
                                                                                                                                     ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:68:46: note: to match this '('
php_imagick_rw_result_t php_imagick_read_file(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC);
                                             ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:71:153: error: expected ')'
php_imagick_rw_result_t php_imagick_write_file(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type, zend_bool adjoin TSRMLS_DC);
                                                                                                                                                        ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:71:47: note: to match this '('
php_imagick_rw_result_t php_imagick_write_file(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type, zend_bool adjoin TSRMLS_DC);
                                              ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:74:112: error: expected ')'
zend_bool php_imagick_stream_handler(php_imagick_object *intern, php_stream *stream, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC);
                                                                                                               ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/php_imagick_file.h:74:37: note: to match this '('
zend_bool php_imagick_stream_handler(php_imagick_object *intern, php_stream *stream, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC);
                                    ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:81:51: error: expected ')'
zend_bool php_imagick_is_url(const char *filename TSRMLS_DC)
                                                  ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:81:29: note: to match this '('
zend_bool php_imagick_is_url(const char *filename TSRMLS_DC)
                            ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:85:90: error: expected ')'
        if (php_stream_locate_url_wrapper(filename, &path_for_open, STREAM_LOCATE_WRAPPERS_ONLY TSRMLS_CC)) {
                                                                                                ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:85:35: note: to match this '('
        if (php_stream_locate_url_wrapper(filename, &path_for_open, STREAM_LOCATE_WRAPPERS_ONLY TSRMLS_CC)) {
                                         ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:91:108: error: expected ')'
zend_bool php_imagick_file_init(struct php_imagick_file_t *file, const char *filename, size_t filename_len TSRMLS_DC)
                                                                                                           ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:91:32: note: to match this '('
zend_bool php_imagick_file_init(struct php_imagick_file_t *file, const char *filename, size_t filename_len TSRMLS_DC)
                               ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:123:40: error: expected ')'
                else if (php_imagick_is_url(filename TSRMLS_CC)) {
                                                     ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:123:30: note: to match this '('
                else if (php_imagick_is_url(filename TSRMLS_CC)) {
                                           ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:142:53: error: expected ')'
        file->absolute_path = expand_filepath(buffer, NULL TSRMLS_CC);
                                                           ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:142:39: note: to match this '('
        file->absolute_path = expand_filepath(buffer, NULL TSRMLS_CC);
                                             ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:160:133: error: expected ')'
int php_imagick_read_image_using_imagemagick(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC)
                                                                                                                                    ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:160:45: note: to match this '('
int php_imagick_read_image_using_imagemagick(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC)
                                            ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:201:133: error: expected ')'
int php_imagick_read_image_using_php_streams(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC)
                                                                                                                                    ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:201:45: note: to match this '('
int php_imagick_read_image_using_php_streams(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC)
                                            ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:207:2: error: expected ')'
        IMAGICK_SET_ERROR_HANDLING_THROW;
        ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:28:133: note: expanded from macro 'IMAGICK_SET_ERROR_HANDLING_THROW'
#  define IMAGICK_SET_ERROR_HANDLING_THROW zend_replace_error_handling(EH_THROW, php_imagick_exception_class_entry, &error_handling TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                                                                                    ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:207:2: note: to match this '('
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:28:71: note: expanded from macro 'IMAGICK_SET_ERROR_HANDLING_THROW'
#  define IMAGICK_SET_ERROR_HANDLING_THROW zend_replace_error_handling(EH_THROW, php_imagick_exception_class_entry, &error_handling TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                      ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:216:3: error: expected ')'
                IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING;
                ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:29:88: note: expanded from macro 'IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING'
#  define IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING   zend_restore_error_handling(&error_handling TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                                       ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:216:3: note: to match this '('
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:29:71: note: expanded from macro 'IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING'
#  define IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING   zend_restore_error_handling(&error_handling TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                      ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:224:3: error: expected ')'
                IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING;
                ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:29:88: note: expanded from macro 'IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING'
#  define IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING   zend_restore_error_handling(&error_handling TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                                       ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:224:3: note: to match this '('
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:29:71: note: expanded from macro 'IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING'
#  define IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING   zend_restore_error_handling(&error_handling TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                      ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:228:2: error: expected ')'
        IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING;
        ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:29:88: note: expanded from macro 'IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING'
#  define IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING   zend_restore_error_handling(&error_handling TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                                       ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:228:2: note: to match this '('
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:29:71: note: expanded from macro 'IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING'
#  define IMAGICK_RESTORE_ERROR_HANDLING   zend_restore_error_handling(&error_handling TSRMLS_CC)
                                                                      ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:255:54: error: expected ')'
int php_imagick_safe_mode_check(const char *filename TSRMLS_DC)
                                                     ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:255:32: note: to match this '('
int php_imagick_safe_mode_check(const char *filename TSRMLS_DC)
                               ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:262:64: error: expected ')'
        if (PG(open_basedir) && php_check_open_basedir_ex(filename, 0 TSRMLS_CC)) {
                                                                      ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:262:51: note: to match this '('
        if (PG(open_basedir) && php_check_open_basedir_ex(filename, 0 TSRMLS_CC)) {
                                                         ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:269:134: error: expected ')'
php_imagick_rw_result_t php_imagick_read_file(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC)
                                                                                                                                     ^
/private/tmp/pear/temp/imagick/imagick_file.c:269:46: note: to match this '('
php_imagick_rw_result_t php_imagick_read_file(php_imagick_object *intern, struct php_imagick_file_t *file, ImagickOperationType type TSRMLS_DC)
                                             ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [imagick_file.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

from sources imagick build failed with some error

System setup

Current PHP version (with 7.4 pecl got some error)

```
php -v
PHP 8.0.0 (cli) (built: Nov 30 2020 13:51:52) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

PECL version

```
pecl version

PEAR Version: 1.10.12
PHP Version: 8.0.0
Zend Engine Version: 4.0.0-dev
Running on: Darwin mbp 20.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.1.0: Sat Oct 31 00:07:11 PDT 2020; root:xnu-7195.50.7~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Clang compiler version

```
cc -v

Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin**strong text**
```

macOS version

```
sw_vers -productVersion

11.0.1
```

Answer (score 12):

If you have installed PHP 8.0 on your MBP from `brew` you can simply build the Imagick from source:

```
git clone https://github.com/Imagick/imagick
cd imagick
phpize && ./configure
make
make install
```

Builded extension should land in similarly directory:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.0_1/pecl/20200930/
```

and finally, you can enable it in your php.ini by adding:

```
extension="imagick.so"
```

Comment: I am getting this. after make command. `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

package only contains 
`-rw-r--r--    1 manishj  staff       0 Feb 17 03:18 Makefile.fragments
-rw-r--r--    1 manishj  staff       0 Feb 17 03:18 Makefile.objects`

Comment: this is great! skip the homebrew install

Comment: @ananas222 It worked! Kindly accept this answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

I have installed imagick extention today.
It seems you need to use php7.4 to compile imagick extention.
If you are using homebrew, you can try `brew install php@7.4` and `brew link --overwrite php@7.4`.
I can successfully compile imagick extention after I run these command.

Here are my system information:
PHP version

```
php -v
PHP 7.4.13 (cli) (built: Nov 30 2020 14:57:43) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.6, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.13, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

PECL version

```
pecl version

PEAR Version: 1.10.12
PHP Version: 7.4.13
Zend Engine Version: 3.4.0
Running on: Darwin Vongola-MBP.local 20.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.1.0: Sat Oct 31 00:07:11 PDT 2020; root:xnu-7195.50.7~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Clang compiler version

```
cc -v

Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

macOS version

```
sw_vers -productVersion

11.0.1
```